# Cannot connect to Mongo Atlas in GCP using VPC peering from GKE cluster

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

issue: My application in GKE is not able to connect with mongo Atlas over VPC peering , however if I run mongosh from a pod in GkE cluster manually using `mongodb+srv://cluster0-pri.mongodb.net/test --apiVersion 1 --username user --password pass` it works well.

I did a little more investigation in my case and figured out something un usual. In application properties I am using
`uri: mongodb+srv://user:pass@cluster0.mongodb.net/test` URI  and because of this it is taking a public route and not going through vpc peering, I test and I am getting same timeout while I try to ssh from a pod to mongo cluster after I remove 0.0.0.0/0 from ip whitelist in atlas.
is there a Better way of making application communicate with mongo in GKE/GCP. or a different way of using URI like below

`mongodb+srv://cluster0.mongodb.net/test?apiVersion=1&username=<user>&password=<pass>`
when I tried this command it say that apiversion is not supported and if I run the same command like  below it works fine
`mongodb+srv://cluster0.mongodb.net/test --apiVersion 1 --username user --password pass`

Comment: Can you please format that stacktrace of your java app so it's readable properly ? I cannot understand it.

From the top of my head is your pod able to resolve the fqdn of mongo ?

Comment: @boredabdel there has been some more investigation and details have come up and I have changed the description of my case . please give it a read

Comment: When you click the "Connect" button in Atlas, it should give you the option to connect via private link, VPC, or public address using shell, compass, or the driver of your choice.  That is the easiest way to find the right connection string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was to add `primary` to the Uri that we are using, when you add `-pri` it will allow the source to resolve at private ip

`uri: mongodb+srv://user:pass@cluster0-pri.mongodb.net/test`

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [cloud NAT](https://dchaykin.medium.com/connect-a-gke-cluster-with-mongodb-atlas-through-cloud-nat-b0ffb2683b7d) instead of VPC peering. From the link shared, you can assign or reserve a static IP address to the router that will be used once you create a cloud NAT.

Since the router's IP address is static (permanent) it's safe to use and whitelist the IP address to MongoDB Atlas under Network Access -> IP Access list instead of using 0.0.0.0/0. Its normal that you have a timeout error message once you remove the whitelist, because it only allows client connection once IP address is whitelisted, you can see this information in this [link](https://medium.com/mongoaudit/how-to-configure-firewall-ip-whitelisting-in-mongodb-atlas-52775102ce3c)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I am using cloud NAT, actually issue is not about the whitlisting of IP, issue is how can I get the VPC peering work because I dont want to send traffic over internet.
because I am using a specific URI to connect and seems peering Is not respecting it